# Building an RGB LED module

Tags: led, led-matrix

I'm a beginner in electronics, read a few books, have solid understanding of the basics.

I would like to make an LED Screen Project I need some quick advice for.

I want my RGB LED Matrixes to be able to join for bigger size screen and have the same controller sending all the signals for each matrix module.

Processor was between FPGA and Xcore by Xmos. I chose the xCore for the C-like programming ability out of box.

How can I put this matrix together for them to be addressable (rgbs) LEDs?

Is there a library for processing video, images to this LED Matrix even if it's separated in modules to still be able to send information from one controller to each matrix/module?

I'm having a hard time beginning, because I mostly find Raspberry Pi and Ardunio controlling a few LEDs, some claims thousand. I don't think they control stadium LED screens with Ardunio module, nor with LED strips, I would like a real guide for a professional, scalable LED screen?

Comment: Not to deflate your ambition (which I admire), but this is a rather sophisticated project for a beginner. Have you done any basic "Hello World" projects, like simply making a single LED blink using a microcontroller?

Comment: I work at a company that produces large LED screens (12 x 4 meters and larger). I can tell you we do not use Arduino or Raspberry Pi as the controller. Think "lots of FPGAs." :)

Comment: is the xCore microcontroller better than FPGA's? i understand that each matrix will be more like a module, like its own little screen even if controlled by one microcontroller, so can i discard FPGA's based on prices and go with a bunch of xCores? http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/XCARD%20XC-1A/XCARD%20XC-1A-ND/2187029

Comment: Microcontroller to FPGA is as apple to orange; different things altogether. We use FPGAs to perform specific, time-sensitive graphical data manipulation (I personally have no experience programming FPGAs). We use microcontrollers to communicate with the hardware for things like error-reporting, control and dimming, etc. Your choice of data processing technology depends ultimately on a lot of factors like your intended refresh rate, color depth (bits used to represent color), drive technology (multiplexed or CC), featureset, etc.

Comment: In other words, to answer your questions, some requirements would need to be defined, such as: What dimensions do you plan on for modules? For assembled screens? What refresh rate? What is the video/image source? Do you want/need to manipulate incoming data (such as gamma correction, frame dropping, resample (i.e. aspect ratio changes), etc? How bright does the display need to be (affects how you drive LEDs)? There are a dozen engineers here that handle those questions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LED screens are cool. *(That's why I went to work for a company that makes them!)* However they're not an easy project for a beginner, or even someone with a bit of experience.

If you're just starting out, the *first* thing to do, as Dan Laks suggested, is grab a microcontroller and make a single LED blink. The "Hello World" of electronics, if you will.

Next, learn how to control multiple LEDs with multiple I/O pins on the microcontroller. From there, I would recommend learning how to drive brighter LEDs or larger loads using transistors. Then [multiplexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexed_display), or driving more LEDs than you have pins for. [Charlieplexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing) is a variant. Next, [shift registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_register), to address even more. Learn about [constant current](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_current) drivers for LEDs. By this point, you will probably know enough to forge ahead on your own.

That's just a sample path you can take, if you want to focus on making LED displays. There are an increasing number of hobby- or beginner-level products designed to make controlling vast numbers of LEDs easier (or at least more affordable). For example, there are various [LED matrix modules](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/683) available from Sparkfun. Or consider the [Rainbowduino](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/rainbowduino-led-driver-platform-atmega-328-p-371.html) driver platform from Seeedstudio. Or there are addressable LED strips as gbulmer mentioned in his answer. There's an interesting project using Arduino Teensy's driving WS2811-based LED strips on [Hack a day](http://hackaday.com/2013/02/25/building-huge-displays-with-led-strips/).

At various points on your journey, feel free to stop by EE.SE and post questions, and learn. Asking how to embark on a huge project obviously leads to many answers, none of which might be 100% "right." But as you go, you may find specific problems to overcome, and that's when asking about it can greatly speed up the process of figuring it out and moving on.

Comment: thanks for everything, over at other forums i'll probably be insulted first, honestly i knew this wasn't a right question as it has no research behind it, but your answer is exactly what i needed to go on, im off to more research and i will order my own led and chips to make it all my self, i been wanting to make a huge led screen running my own OS for years and years

Answer (score 2):

Look at [WS2812](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812.pdf) or [WS2812B](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf).

They are an RGB LED in a 5x5mm package.

As well as a red, green and blue LED, each one contains the PWM circuit to control brightness of each colour. Give it power (straight from a power supply), and it'll do the rest.

Further it handles one-wire serial data input and output. They handle data at a rate of 800kbits/second.

So it is possible to wire hundreds in series into one 'string', talk to the string with a *single wire* from e.g. an MCU, and change all of them in less than the refresh time of a TV picture (i.e. under 1/100th of a second).

It handles making the correct colour, using its built-in PWM, without any further processing. It will carry on showing the same colour as long as it is powered.

So you only need to provide power to it, and send data to it when you want it to change colour.

You can buy small numbers of them ready assembled so that you can practice, and become confident that you understand how to use them for a modest amounts of money.

For example [8 RGB pixels](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1426), though there are *lots* of products and vendors. You can buy individual components for between 10¢ and 20¢ from China, as well as flexible strips, panels etc.